# right query code for the multirelation table data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm encountering an issue with displaying data in my Blade template. Let me first describe the table relationships:
[image: Table Relations]

Here is the code from my controller:

```php
$datamhs = DB::table('nilai_tugas')->where('nilai_tugas.id_modulkelas', $id)
            ->leftJoin('tugas', 'nilai_tugas.id_tugas', '=', 'tugas.id_tugas')
            ->leftJoin('mahasiswa_kelas', 'mahasiswa_kelas.id_mahasiswa_kelas', '=', 'nilai_tugas.id_mahasiswa_kelas')
            ->leftJoin('mahasiswa', 'mahasiswa.id_mahasiswa', '=', 'mahasiswa_kelas.id_mahasiswa')
            ->select(DB::raw('mahasiswa.nim as nim, mahasiswa_kelas.id_mahasiswa_kelas, mahasiswa.nama_mahasiswa as nama_mahasiswa'))
            ->get();
```

Below is the Blade template:

```html
<div class="tab-content p-3 text-muted">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="navtabs-mhs" role="tabpanel">
        <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
               style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>NIM</th>
                    <th>Nama Mahasiswa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($datamhs as $x)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $x->nim }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $x->nama_mahasiswa }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem that arises is the table displays 20 rows because it references the `nilai_tugas` table, which contains 20 `id_mahasiswa_kelas` entries. This can be seen in the linked image showing the issue:

[image: Problematic Output]

However, my expectation is for the table to display data based on the `mahasiswa` table, as seen in the image below. It should only show data for 10 `mahasiswa` records.

[image: Expected Outcome]